# Container element within <header> not displaying

Tags: css, html

I'm using the 'section' element as a container within the 'header' element.

The container is not displaying in any way.

Live: http://blnr.org/testing

HTML

```
    <!-- start pagewrap -->
    <div id="pagewrap">

        <!-- start header -->
        <header>

            <section id="container">    

            </section>

        </header>
        <!-- end header -->

    </div>
    <!-- end pagewrap -->
```

CSS

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border-bottom: thin solid #C6D9F1;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

header section #container {
    width: 900px;
    height: 30px;
    border: thin dotted black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a tiny mistake:

change: `header section #container` to `header section#container` in your CSS as in:

```
header section#container {
    width: 900px;
    height: 30px;
    border: thin dotted black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

What you did is basically looking for an element width `id="container"` **inside** the section.

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML5 - using a space in CSS meaning "and inside look for".. you could have done: `header #container` this would have worked for you.. however `header section #container` means look for `header` - then inside for `section` - then inside for `#container`

Answer (score 0):

The space between `section` and `#container` means it's a selector for an element with the id 'container' *inside* the section block. Remove the space:

```
header section#container {
    width: 900px;
    height: 30px;
    border: thin dotted black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```